# mysql getting intersection of one table to three tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like this:

```
units
+---------+---------+
|    id   |   unit  |
+---------+---------+
|    1    |   lbs   |
+---------+---------+
|    2    |   cm    |
+---------+---------+
|    3    |   lit   |
+---------+---------+
|    4    |   cum   |
+---------+---------+

material
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | unit_id | material_name|
+----+---------+--------------+
| 1  |    3    |      pcb     |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 2  |    4    |      lbc     |
+----+---------+--------------+

equipment
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | unit_id |equipment_name|
+----+---------+--------------+
| 1  |    1    |      ber     |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 2  |    4    |      war     |
+----+---------+--------------+

project_items
+----+---------+--------------+
| id | unit_id | project_name |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 1  |    1    |      sec     |
+----+---------+--------------+
| 2  |    3    |      dum     |
+----+---------+--------------+
```

I want to get only the `unit_id` where only exist in other 3 tables

[image]

I tried using inner join

```
SELECT u.id FROM  units u 
INNER JOIN material m ON u.id = m.unit_id
INNER JOIN equipment e ON u.id = e.unit_id
INNER JOIN project_items i ON u.id = i.unit_id;
```

but this only select `id` that intersect on all tables, any ideas?

Comment: I want to get the `id` intersection of the `material`, `equipment` and `project` table on the `units` table

Comment: So for your sample data, what should the result be?

Comment: in this case since the `material` have `unit_id` 3 and 4 and `equipment` `unit_id` 1 and 4 and `project_items` `unit_id` 1 and 3 so the result would be 1 3 4 but not 2 since it doesn't exist in other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `IN` with `UNION ALL`:

```
select *
from units
where id in (
  select unit_id from material
  union all
  select unit_id from equipment
  union all 
  select unit_id from project_items)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/999b2/1)

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and attila?

Comment: @newbie -- As attila points out, there are multiple ways of doing the same thing.  I would imagine the union would be faster than three separate subqueries, but your best bet is to try it out.  Glad we could help.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably quite a few ways of doing this, but this can be as simple as using EXISTS, like so:

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM  units u 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM material m
    WHERE  u.id=m.unit_id)
  OR EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM equipment e
    WHERE  u.id=e.unit_id)
  OR EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM project_items I
    WHERE  u.id = i.unit_id)
```